# values are getting overwritten in the table -PDFbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to display the set of records in rows and columns. Am getting output but the thing is, it is getting overlapped. should i modify the loop can someone pls suggest.

```
 ArrayList<ResultRecord> Records = new ArrayList<ResultRecord>(MainRestClient.fetchResultRecords(this.savedMainLog));
 for(j=0; j<Records.size(); j++)
           {
                Row<PDPage> row4 = table.createRow(100.0f);
                Cell<PDPage> cell10 = row4.createCell(15.0f, temp.getNumber());
                Cell<PDPage> cell11 = row4.createCell(45.0f, temp.getDescription());
                Cell<PDPage> cell12 = row4.createCell(15.0f, temp.getStatus());
                Cell<PDPage> cell13 = row4.createCell(25.0f, temp.getRemarks());
                }
```

---

The below is the full code for opening a PDF file. I want to retreive set of records in the row4 in the corresponding cells. But the is over written one above the another.
Expected output:
IT should display one below the another.
Is the overlapping reason,is it because of defining the row as **row4**.

```
 try {
                //table.draw();

                cell.setFontSize(12);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Stultuske The values which it is getting fetched are overwritten in the rows and columns

Comment: you just repeat the statement, there is no additional explanation.  I hope you understand that we don't know what table is, or what half of your code does, so we can't guess from that neither.

Comment: @Stultuske Apologies for the short content, Now i have explained it in the post.

Comment: if you don't put them in a loop, but one after another, do they then print all on the same spot as well? have you confirmed that it's actually about the loop? or is it perhaps because the size of the page is limited?

Comment: Also, have you debugged and checked that your List contains what you think it contains?

Comment: without the second loop, only one row is getting display being overwritten. If i put the loop then overwritten is happening with repeated values. Nope size of the page is getting extended

Comment: yeah result is getting fetched correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should clarify the table drawing library you use. PDFBox only is the underlying PDF library. Considering the classes used I would assume you are using Boxable on top of it.

Furthermore, the reason why all the tables are printed over each other is that you start each table at the same position on the same page, you use

```
BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yPosition, yStartNewPage,
        bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, document, page, true, drawContent);
```

without ever changing `yPosition` or `page`.

To get one table after the other, you have to update `yPosition` and `page` accordingly, e.g. by using the return value of `table.draw()` and the state of `table` then, i.e. by replacing

```
table.draw();
```

by

```
yPosition = table.draw();
page = table.getCurrentPage();
```

Comment: Yes, used the Boxable..Thank you so much for the help.